# Docker push "denied: requested access to the resource is denied"

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm on `Ubuntu Linux Server 20.04` and this is my first time pushing something to Docker so I just created a dummy container locally and it worked. Following some tutorials online, the `hello-world` example also works just fine.

Here's what I've tried:

1. I create a repo online

   - I've tried all of this for both public and private repos.
   - I just have a stardard account, this is not an organization.
2. `docker login` (Which succeeds)

   - I've also tried `docker login -u <username>`
   - I've tried with and without the `pass` program (Both succeed in logging in)
   - To make sure it's not reporting a false"success" message I tried using an incorrect password and it failed accordingly so the login appears to work.
3. `docker tag <local repo name>:latest <username>/<online repo name>:v1`

   - I've tried a myriad of other ways such as the following but they all produce the same error
   - `docker tag <local repo name>:latest <username>/<repo name>:latest`
   - `docker tag <local repo name> <username>/<repo name>:latest`
   - `docker tag <local repo name>:latest <username>/<repo name>:v1`
   - `docker tag <local repo name> <username>/<repo name>:v1`
   - `docker tag <local repo name>:latest <username>/<repo name>`
   - `docker tag <local repo name> <username>/<repo name>`
4. `docker push <username>/<online repo name>:v1`

   - I've also tried `docker push <username>/<online repo name>`
5. This is the output

```
The push refers to repository [docker.io/<username>/<online repo name>]
3c8373fcfed2: Preparing
dc881c014b38: Preparing
933337b6e971: Preparing
10e1cb1c03c2: Preparing
770786057cc0: Preparing
570175f149e2: Waiting
3e207b409db3: Waiting
denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

At this point I've just given up, I don't understand why it's being denied and not pushing but I've gone through 2 Google pages of links trying to research this spanning 2 days so I don't know what else to do.

Comment: did you try the solution mentioned in https://github.com/docker/hub-feedback/issues/1222#issuecomment-355803773 ?

Comment: @jakub Tried that just now, still same error

Comment: @jakub I found the problem, in attempt to not store my docker password in plaintext I'm using the recommended "pass" program on the Docker website. If I give up and just allow my password to be in plain text it works. This is an issue with Pass or Docker's communication with pass. I'm not happy about having to have my password in plain text but it's either that or I can't push to Docker Hub.

Answer (score 3):

In attempt to not store my docker password unencrypted I'm using the recommended `pass` program on the Docker website. If I give up and just allow my password to be unencrypted it works. This is an issue with `pass` or Docker's communication with `pass`. I'm not happy about having to have my password unencrypted but it's either that or I can't push to Docker Hub.

There are 4 solutions for not storing your password unencrypted and the only one for Linux servers is `pass`.

Comment: I am so glad I have found your gracious answer to this problem, I too have been squandering a few days on this, but your answer was the solution for me. I also followed Docker recommended programs for encryption to fix the glaring unencrypted message, but it pass was the issue all along. Perhaps this is due to pass injecting a line into config.json and its encryption conflicting with docker authentication at https://index.docker.io/v1/? I am wondering if there is an alternative? Hoping your answer can reach more audience, as I have not seen another solution for this particular setup.